# Issue while importing Psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

When I import `psycopg2` in IDLE it is crashing and I was unable to do any testing due to this. I tried reinstalling python and `psycopg2` multiple times but the issue still persists.

Can anyone help with this?

Attached an error screen shot [image: error screen shot].

Comment: Please add the content of the Python and the error Windows to your question **as code-formatted text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the postgres server,Python(new versions) and all its dependencies and reinstalled again, after that it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for Psycopg2, a symlink is created. As I can see from you screenshot that System Integrity Protection is enabled. You have to disable it (by command `csrutil disable` and reboot) and then create a symlink as follows:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
```

In my case i have installed PgSQL 9.6.
Please read [OS X Sierra, PostgreSQL and Psycopg2](https://medium.com/pixel-heart/os-x-sierra-postgresql-and-psycopg2-42c0c95acb23) article for further errors and detail.